# Add accents between values used for REGEXREPLACE (Google Sheets)

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, regexp-replace

I have this formula:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(UNIQUE(TRIM(TRANSPOSE(SPLIT(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(QUERY(TRANSPOSE(
REGEXREPLACE(REGEXEXTRACT(INDIRECT("T2:T"&COUNTA(T2:T)+1), REPT("(.)",
LEN(INDIRECT("T2:T"&COUNTA(T2:T)+1)))), "['A-Za-z\.-]", )),,999^99)),,999^99), " ")))))
```

Among the values to use are these:

```
"['A-Za-z\.-]"
```

When trying to add the accents (`` "['A-Za-z\.-’´`]" ``), it turns out not to work, it seems that the formula does not understand that these values can also be used, how do I include these accents within the formula?

↓

`’` `´` `` ` ``

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the regex would need to list them all like:

```
"['A-Za-z\.-áéíóúàèìòù]"
```